# How to SELECT N rows starting after id M with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am making a page where users can make posts as well as delete their posts. As the user scrolls to the bottom of the page, I want 3 old posts to be pulled from the server and displayed at the bottom of the page. Everything worked perfectly until I started deleting posts. $postId represents the last post to currently be displayed. Here is my currently code.

```
$largest = $pollId - 1;
$smallest = $largest - 3;
if($smallest < 1){$smallest = 1;}
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "password", "db");
$q = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM poll WHERE id BETWEEN $smallest AND $largest order by id desc");
```

Since users can delete posts, id values in ascending order may read 21, 22, 27, 31, 35. If the last post id is 35, then I want to pull posts associated with id 31, 27, and 22. How do I create a mysqli_query to accomplish this task.

Comment: Don't actually delete. Have an `active` field and then only select active ones. Also you should parameterize the query.

Comment: there are positive points and negative points about soft deletes.. The biggest negative one is GDPR (EU 's General Data Protection Regulation )  @user3783243

Comment: I haven't heard of soft deletes before. I'll look into it, but wouldn't saving posts that have been deleted be a waist of server space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM poll
WHERE id < $postID
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 3
```